# How to work out single leg ice skating?

Tags: technique, training, ice-skating

Some people say "wiggle", some "weaving", anyway, it is about skating on just one skate.

I saw some videos how it looks like but only one video how to actually learn that move -- pity the video is about roller skates: 
[How to improve your balance, stability and steering on inline skates or rollerblades.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjE-hHKFghc) -- I am not that sure if everything applies to ice skating.

For now I can only glide (no propulsion) on one foot, I cannot gain speed, and eventually I stop. I go ice skating daily and for 2 weeks -- no progress.

Maybe there is is some exercise which would help me "catch" the drill and go further do full wiggle.

My goal 
[Ice Hockey - Skate Forward and Backward One Foot Wiggles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vo-Wv54jmfg)
 :-)

Answer (score 3):

The maneuver you are referencing is also known as a "power pull" or an "edge pull". It is a required component of the USFSA Pre-Juvenile Moves In the Field (MIF) test (http://www.usfsa.org/Shell.asp?sid=42292). It's a fairly difficult move and takes a lot of practice on inside and especially outside edges.  In the USFSA testing structure, the two tests prior to Pre-Juv MIF ([Preliminary](http://www.usfsa.org/Shell.asp?sid=42291) and [Pre-preliminary](http://www.usfsa.org/Shell.asp?sid=42288)) involve a lot of edge work in preparation for more advanced moves like the power pull. You might start practicing with the more basic edge moves outlined in the first two tests and work your way up to the power pull.

Just like anything, all it takes is time and practice. Don't feel bad if you are not getting it right away. It took my daughter about 2 years to be able to do a power pull the length of a rink unassisted. Just keep working on it.

Comment: It also takes strength.

Comment: It is "fairly difficult", so it kills me to see that the only easier moves are called "preliminary" and "pre-preliminary". Someday I aspire to pre-juvenile!